# Variable not displaying the path for Folder browsed in GUI using Powershell

Tags: winforms, powershell

Using windows form to create a User Form for the power shell code, successfully able to trigger the folder browse functionality. After selecting the Folder from browse the value is stored in `$FolderBrowse.SelectedPath`  .When trying to populate the value on form its not working

```
$BROWSEButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$FolderBrowse = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog -Property @{ ShowNewFolderButton  = $false }
$BROWSEButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,95)
$BROWSEButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$BROWSEButton.Text = "Browse"
$BROWSEButton.Add_Click({$x=$objTextBox.Text;$FolderBrowse.ShowDialog()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($BROWSEButton)

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,60)
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$objLabel.Text = "Selected Path : "+$FolderBrowse.SelectedPath
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The label shows up when the folder selector loads up. So it will be better you attach it with an add_click event with button (Don't set $objLabel.Text value)

```
$BROWSEButton.Add_Click({
  $FolderBrowser.ShowDialog()
  $objLabel.Text = "Selected Path : "+$FolderBrowse.SelectedPath
})
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason its not working? because after executing the code when i check in `$FolderBrowse.SelectedPath` the value is present but it is not assigning to $path

Comment: Because all controls are added the form and all load in same time, that is the cause. In the answer the assignment happens after clicking the button.